# Error en Proyecto Web con MAVEN APACHE ECLIPSE y librería interna

Tags: webservice, tomcat, jersey

Tengo un proyecto web dinámico creado con Maven, estoy usando Eclipse y Tomcat para ejecutar el servicio web. Utilizando Jersey 8.

El problema es cuando quiero agregar como dependencia otro proyecto propio en el pom o como jar library me da classNotFoundException.

Compila bien y no me da errores en las clases pero si al  momento de deployarlo en el servidor Tomcat 9.

Alquien podría ayudarme u orientarme ??

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

finalmente agregue la librería manualmente en la carpeta libs ubicada dentro de WEB-INF.
Gracias.